# LabelEncoder cannot inverse_transform (unseen labels) after imputing missing values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation, label-encoding

I'm at a beginner to intermediate data science level. I want to impute missing values from a dataframe using `knn`.

As the dataframe contains strings and `floats`, I need to encode / decode values using `LabelEncoder`.

My method is as follows:

> 1. Replace NaN to be able to encode
> 2. Encode the text values and put them in a dictionary
> 3. Retrieve the NaN (previously converted) to be imputed with knn
> 4. Assign values with knn
> 5. Decode values from the dictionary

Unfortunately, in the last step, imputing values adds new values that cannot be decoded (`unseen labels` error message).

Could you please explain to me what I am doing wrong? Ideally help me to correct it please. Before concluding, I wanted to say that I know that there are other tools like `OneHotEncoder`, but I don't know them well enough and I found LabelEncoder much more intuitive because you can see it directly in the dataframe (where `LabelEncoder` provides an array).

Please find below an example of my method, **thank you very much for your help** :

[1]

```
# Import libraries. 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Name':['Jack', np.nan, 'Victoria', 'Nicolas', 'Victor', 'Brad'], 'Age':[59, np.nan, 29, np.nan, 65, 50], 'Car color':['Blue', 'Black', np.nan, 'Black', 'Grey', np.nan], 'Height ':[177, 150, np.nan, 180, 175, 190]} 

# Make a DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Print the output. 
df 

Output : 
    Name    Age     Car color   Height
0   Jack    59.0    Blue    177.0
1   NaN     NaN     Black   150.0
2   Victoria    29.0    NaN     NaN
3   Nicolas     NaN     Black   180.0
4   Victor  65.0    Grey    175.0
5   Brad    50.0    NaN     190.0
```

[2]

```
# LabelEncoder does not work with NaN values, so I replace them with value '1000' : 
df = df.replace(np.nan, 1000)

# And to avoid errors, str columns must be set as strings (even '1000' value) : 
df[['Name','Car color']] = df[['Name','Car color']].astype(str)

df

Output 
    Name    Age     Car color   Height
0   Jack    59.0    Blue    177.0
1   1000    1000.0  Black   150.0
2   Victoria    29.0    1000    1000.0
3   Nicolas     1000.0  Black   180.0
4   Victor  65.0    Grey    175.0
5   Brad    50.0    1000    190.0
```

[3]

```
# Import LabelEncoder library : 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# define labelencoder :
le = LabelEncoder()

# Import defaultdict library to make a dict of labelencoder :
from collections import defaultdict

# Initiate a dict of LabelEncoder values :
encoder_dict = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)

# Make a new dataframe of LabelEncoder values :
df[['Name','Car color']] = df[['Name','Car color']].apply(lambda x: encoder_dict[x.name].fit_transform(x))

# Show output :
df

Output 
    Name    Age     Car color   Height
0   2   59.0    2   177.0
1   0   1000.0  1   150.0
2   5   29.0    0   1000.0
3   3   1000.0  1   180.0
4   4   65.0    3   175.0
5   1   50.0    0   190.0
```

[4]

```
#Reverse back 1000 to missing values in order to impute them : 
df = df.replace(1000, np.nan)
df

Output 

    Name    Age     Car color   Height
0   2   59.0    2   177.0
1   0   NaN     1   150.0
2   5   29.0    0   NaN
3   3   NaN     1   180.0
4   4   65.0    3   175.0
5   1   50.0    0   190.0
```

[5]

```
# Import knn imputer library to replace impute missing values : 
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

# Define imputer : 
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)

# impute and reassign index/colonnes : 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(imputer.fit_transform(df)),columns = df.columns)
df

Output 

    Name    Age     Car color   Height
0   2.0     59.0    2.0     177.0
1   0.0     47.0    1.0     150.0
2   5.0     29.0    0.0     165.0
3   3.0     44.0    1.0     180.0
4   4.0     65.0    3.0     175.0
5   1.0     50.0    0.0     190.0
```

[6]

```
# Decode data : 
inverse_transform_lambda = lambda x: encoder_dict[x.name].inverse_transform(x)

# Apply it to df -> THIS IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS :
df[['Name','Car color']].apply(inverse_transform_lambda)
```

Error message :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-55-8a5e369215f6> in <module>()
----> 1 df[['Name','Car color']].apply(inverse_transform_lambda)

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6926             kwds=kwds,
   6927         )
-> 6928         return op.get_result()
   6929 
   6930     def applymap(self, func):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    290 
    291         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 292         self.apply_series_generator()
    293 
    294         # wrap results

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    319             try:
    320                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 321                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    322                     keys.append(v.name)
    323             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-54-f16f4965b2c4> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 inverse_transform_lambda = lambda x: encoder_dict[x.name].inverse_transform(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in inverse_transform(self, y)
    297                     "y contains previously unseen labels: %s" % str(diff))
    298         y = np.asarray(y)
--> 299         return self.classes_[y]
    300 
    301     def _more_tags(self):

IndexError: ('arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type', 'occurred at index Name')
```

Comment: I've discovered this same error in stack, may be it helps you? Let me know
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57108956/8333806

Comment: bro i have followed same process but it is not decoding for me and there is no error as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comment you should do

```
# Decode data : 
inverse_transform_lambda = lambda x: encoder_dict[x.name].inverse_transform(x.astype(int)) # or x[].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Abdoulsn for your kind help, this works well ! I noticed that the `str` columns are thus "spared" by the `knn` imputation, since decoding gives me back `1000` (and thus `NaN`, so missing values). 
Finally, I could for example make it easier by making a `knn` imputation only on `float` columns. But I wonder if `knn` didn't take into account the value `'1000'` in the imputation. What do you think about this? Thanks again.

Comment: **EDIT :** of course, `knn` takes other values in the `str` columns, so the original method can be used (and should be better than just imputing `float`columns) ! Sorry for having asked such question, I am tired !

Comment: happy that it helped you. There many question which already are answered feel free to check them sometimes before asking :)